# Updating plot label in a ggplot batch function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, graph, batch-processing

I have a simple function that will plot the number of individuals collected (Catch = yaxis) by the distance from the edge of the forest (Trap = xaxis), for i = 1 to 89 species in a dataframe. The dataframe has 7 columns as follows: Type, Stand, Line, Trap (0,10,15,25,50,75m from edge), Species (8 character text name for each of the 89 species), and Catch (which is a numeric count total).
I can get the graphs to plot fine, however, I would like to add the name of each species to each graph so I know which species has been graphed.

Here is my simple function:
df=stap1
stap1$Species is a text column containing the 89 species: Acidcren, Acidquad...Tachbasa

```
    plot_fun = by(stap1, stap1$Species, function(i) {
      ggplot(i) +
          geom_point(aes(Trap, Catch))
     })
```

The function simply plots Catch on yaxis ~ Trap distance on xaxis, by each species.
Any ideas how I could modify the function to include the species names?

Comment: try to add +labs(title = Species) after the geom_point() function.

Comment: Why not just use `facet_wrap`? Instead of having multiple graphs, you could have one graph with multiple semiplots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the name of the `Species` using `+ labs(title = unique(i$Species))`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `iris`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

by(iris, iris$Species, function(i) {
  ggplot(i) +
    geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    labs(title = unique(i$Species))
})
#> iris$Species: setosa
```

[image]

```
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> iris$Species: versicolor
```

[image]

```
#> ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#> iris$Species: virginica
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that worked perfectly!! I tried other syntax but could not get it to work. Awesome.